# android annotation after checkout from svn

Tags: android-annotations

i set up the project using android annotation, then check in to the svn after the checkout from the SVN ,the problem started ,please do something if anybody experienced in this

08-14 13:02:31.097: W/dalvikvm(16362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41948ba8)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{*}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.MainActivity*" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-14 13:02:31.097: W/System.err(16362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ".MainActivity_" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
08-14 13:02:31.107: W/System.err(16362):    ... 11 more

Comment: Your problem is that generated classes are not included in your APK. What IDE or build system do you use to create the APK?

Comment: i'm using here android annotation, here what i found the annotation files are not generated by the anootation

Comment: I ask again: what IDE or build system do you use? You should post the config files for that.

Comment: ADT v22, whats i'm working was fine, after i updated in to SVN after checkout the problem started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
latter i found this answer 

->Right click the project
->select Property
->select Java Compiler
->select Annotation processing 
->Select Factory Path

 there remove the jar file and re add the jar file, the do Apply, then give OK
```